# Dynamic Tabs with RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, tabs

I'm using `FirebaseFirestore` to store group strings and I want to fetch them and show them inside a `TabLayout`. This means that the number of tabs and text would be set dynamically from the database. I'm not sure about how to fully implement this. Any help?

Comment: Refer to this
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278339/how-to-add-dynamic-fragment-tab-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278339/how-to-add-dynamic-fragment-tab-items)

Comment: but this does not handle data from firebase